# Finding the smallest negative number and the smallest positive number in an array of transactions using .each

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of transaction data:

```
transactions = [50_000, -2_000, -25_000, 4_000, -12_000, 5_000, -800, -900, 43_000, -30_000, 15_000, 62_000, -50_000, 42_000]
```

and I want to retrieve the largest negative number (smallest withdrawal) and the smallest positive number (smallest deposit) from that list. Withdrawals are represented by negative numbers. Deposits are all positive numbers.

I am having trouble understanding the logic I would need to get the desired results (smallest withdrawal and smallest deposit)

Below, I am currently getting the largest withdrawal and largest deposit from the array:

```
smallest_withdrawal = 0
transactions.each do |transaction|
  if transaction < smallest_withdrawal
    smallest_withdrawal = transaction
  end
end
puts smallest_withdrawal

smallest_deposit = 0
transactions.each do |transaction|
  if transaction > smallest_deposit
    smallest_deposit = transaction
  end
end
puts smallest_deposit
```

I am not getting error messages, but instead of getting my desired results, I am getting their opposites. I need help with my logical operators.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there will be at least one deposit and one withdrawal? If not, what is to be returned if there are none of either type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about leveraging Ruby's builtin operations to define suitable subsets for withdrawals and deposits?

```
smallest_withdrawal = transactions.select { |x| x < 0 }.max
smallest_deposit = transactions.select { |x| x > 0 }.min
```

This could also be written as:

```
smallest_withdrawal = transactions.select(&:negative?).max
smallest_deposit = transactions.select(&:positive?).min
```

Yet another variant would be:

```
negatives, positives = transactions.partition(&:negative?)
smallest_withdrawal = negatives.max
smallest_deposit = positives.min
```

Finally, if you're willing to go arcane to get a one-liner:

```
smallest_withdrawal, smallest_deposit = transactions.partition(&:negative?).map(&:minmax).flatten[1..2]
```

I wouldn't recommend that for readability reasons, though.

Answer (score 5):

One can make a single pass through the array. It it were guaranteed there would be at least one deposit and one withdrawal, one could write:

```
def closest_to_zero(transactions)
  transactions.minmax_by { |t| 1.0/t }
end
```

```
closest_to_zero(transactions)
  #=> [-800, 4000]
```

See [Enumerable#minmax_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by). If there could be no deposits or no withdrawals (but there were at least two transactions) we'd have to uglify the code:

```
def closest_to_zero(transactions) 
  transactions.minmax_by { |t| 1.0/t }.then do |mn,mx|
    [mn > 0 ? nil : mn, mx < 0 ? nil : mx]
  end
end

closest_to_zero [ 1,  2,  3]
  #=> [nil, 1] 
closest_to_zero [-1, -2, -3]
  #=> [-1, nil]
```

See [Object#then](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-then) (aka `yield_self`). `yield_self` was new in Ruby v2.5, `then` in v2.6.